# Error 401 Unauthorized when trying to access Outlook O365 API through own v2.0 Web-API

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, office365api

Currently I am trying to create some type of Mail Management in PHP, mainly to create mail redirections and set automatic responses. The goal is that our employees (or more precise, the group leaders) can authenticate themselves in our internal authorization system, and then submit a form to create a redirection (+ automatic response) for employee X, for example if X called in sick.
We know that there is the "delegate" function in Exchange Online, but our users don't use it anyway ...

All went well until now, and the documentation and searching the web did not help me with the following problem.
As the title suggests, everything is done through an application registered in the [Application Registration Portal](https://apps.dev.microsoft.com). I assigned the needed permissions and accepted them with an administrator account.
If I only needed the Graph API, everything would be fine, probably. But I also need the "old" O365 Outlook REST API, because only this API has the capability to change mailbox rules (only in the beta API though, but this is currently more like a "proof of concept").

DISCLAIMER: The following PHP code is very ugly, but this is just to test if it even works.
Also I can't use cURL, because the production system does not have the extension installed. Just FYI.

This is the Function I am using to get my access token (sensible parts replaced):

```
function getAccessToken($scope) {
    global $auth;
    $url = 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenant>/oauth2/v2.0/token';
    $data = array(
        'client_id' => '<My App ID>',
        'scope' => $scope,
        'client_secret' => '<secret token>',
        'grant_type' => 'client_credentials',
    );

    $options = array(
        'http' => array(
            'method' => 'POST',
            'proxy' => 'tcp://192.168.5.1:8080',
            'header' => array('Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded', 'Proxy-Authorization: Basic ' . $auth),
            'content' => http_build_query($data)
        )
    );
    $context = stream_context_create($options);
    $response = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);
    $result = json_decode($response);
    return $result->access_token;
}
```

I get a GUID this way (and access the Graph API similarly, but I need the O365 API):

```
$access_token = getAccessToken('https://graph.microsoft.com/.default');
$user = rawurlencode("mail eq 'email@example.com'");
$url = 'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?$filter=' . $user;


$authorization = 'Authorization: Bearer ' . $access_token;

$options = array(
    'http' => array(
        'method' => 'GET',
        'proxy' => 'tcp://192.168.5.1:8080',
        'header' => array('Content-Type: application/json', 'Proxy-Authorization: Basic ' . $auth, $authorization),
    )
);

$context = stream_context_create($options);
$response = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);
$result = json_decode($response);
$user_id = $result->value[0]->id;
```

This works fine for other Graph API Elements using the graph(dot)microsoft(dot)com/v1.0/ endpoint as well. I can get a list of all our Users, get all mails of one specific user and so on.
But if I try to access the outlook(dot)office(dot)com/api/v2.0 endpoint to, for example, list the mails of a user (in the user_id@tenant_id format), I get the 401 Unauthorized error (Link restrictions are nice).

Now, the problem seems to be the different permission scopes (User.MailRead vs outlook(dot)office(dot)com/mail.read), which makes it impossible to use the same access key. But I only ever found help doing this with user authentication.

The documentation is not really helpful in my opinion, because it is halfway Graph, halfway old API. For example, the only information about doing this with the v2.0 authorization is using the graph permissions.

Now the question(s): How can I use my app without user sign-in to access the old REST API? How can I generate a valid access token allowing me to access all Users, all Mailbox settings and all Mailbox rules through the O365 Outlook REST API?

If you need further informations, don't hesitate to ask!

Answer (score 0):

Apps that have been registered using the converged application registration, can only use a [limited set of APIs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-v2-limitations#restrictions-on-services-and-apis).

I think you need to register your application in the Azure Portal to be able to grant it access to the API you need.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.
According to the doc you linked, It seems like the v2.0 endpoint does support the Outlook REST API, which is the one I need to use. I still think that the permission scopes are the real problem. The token I get when supplying [https://outlook.office.com](https://outlook.office.com) as resource does not contain any "role" field, unlike my Graph API request to receive the user ID. Do I have to somehow assign the Outlook REST API roles / permissions seperately?

Answer (score 0):

The v2 Endpoint is supports by both Outlook REST API but you'll need to be explicit in your scopes. This is done by requesting the fully qualified scope to specify the Outlook API. Without an explicit qualification it will assume you're requesting scopes for Graph.

For example, requesting the scope `Mail.Read` will result in requesting this scope for Microsoft Graph. In order to use Outlook's REST API you'll need to qualify it with `https://outlook.office.com/` so it reads `https://outlook.office.com/Mail.Read` as the scope.

For more information, I suggest looking at [Translating between Graph and Outlook](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/rest/compare-graph-outlook#translating-between-graph-and-outlook).

As an aside, you can also qualify Graph scopes with `https://graph.microsoft.com/` in the same way. I often do this in my code so its always clear which API I'm requesting.

Comment: Thanks for answering. I can't test it right now directly, but there is one question I have right now: Is this translation also applicable to Applications without user authentication like mine? Using application permissions granted by an AD administrator I mean.